# Can we make a URL Connection with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, url, google-apps-script, connection

I've been searching for it all day, yesterday... I'm trying to fetch a URL using UrlFetchApp, but I need to login to the website to get Member's content, is this possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Likely as not no. If you are literally looking to scrape content visible only after login.

Depending on the site there maybe a (un)published API to retrieve data, but this is still far from common.